# How to compare 'μ' and 'µ' in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, unicode, string-comparison

I fall into a surprising issue.

I loaded a text file in my application and I have some logic which compares the value having µ.

And I realized that even if the texts are same the compare value is false.

```
 Console.WriteLine("μ".Equals("µ")); // returns false
 Console.WriteLine("µ".Equals("µ")); // return true
```

In later line the character  µ is copy pasted.

Any idea will be helpful.