# Setting Custom Rules for String Comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string, compare

I need to compare strings containing Turkish characters (üğşıçö). Unfortunately, culture settings do not satisfy my needs. I have to broaden the rules to make it more flexible. Program should recognize the following:

- S = Ş = s = ş
- G = Ğ = g = ğ
- O = Ö = o = ö
- C = Ç = c = ç
- U = Ü = u = ü
- I = İ = ı = i

So users could input in standard English keyboard. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try solutions from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674577/how-to-compare-unicode-characters-that-look-alike/20674360#20674360

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **String.Replace** to turn your strings into some sort of "Middle Format" that recognizes Turkish characters and English characters to be the same, and compare them after? Would that satisfy your requirements?

```
bool MiddleCompare(string eng, string turk)
{
    //Replace turkish characters with english here
    //Compare the newly formatted string, return true/false
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thanks.