# Avoid Micron symbol μ to appear as M when using CSS text-transform: uppercase

Tags: css, html, uppercase

I have this HTML:

```
<p class="uppercase">
    aaaaaaaa 9″¾ 5μm
</p>
```

This CSS:

```
p.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I get this result:

```
AAAAAAAA 9″¾ 5ΜM
```

How can I obtain this?

```
AAAAAAAA 9″¾ 5μM
```

```css
p.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<p class="uppercase">
  aaaaaaaa 9″¾ 5μm
</p>
```

Comment: Unicode seems to define an uppercase for the micro symbol ([U+00B5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00B5/index.htm)) in the same way as it does for the actual Greek letter ([U+03BC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03BC/index.htm)). I don't know if this is for [normalization purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674577/how-to-compare-unicode-characters-that-look-alike/20674872#20674872). Not sure there's a way around this save for wrapping the micro in its own element and keeping that element lowercase.

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of months ago. Solved it the way @BoltClock suggested.  https://jsfiddle.net/cxz28552/1/

Comment: all i see in ff is 3/4"?

Answer (score -1):

I have found one alternative solution.

1. Please remove **text-transform: uppercase** style
2. You can use **strtoupper** PHP function

Like: `<h2><?php echo strtoupper( "µ-Title" ); ?></h2>`

Comment: (I didn't downvote you, but other people have because you're assuming the OP is using PHP when they haven't said that). Also... there is no point using a runtime function to transform a const/literal when you can just edit the literal...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

try this code without style

```
<p class="">
aaaaaaaa 9″¾ 5μm
</p>
```

More information : http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/lowercase-letter-mu-micro-sign-micron-ascii-code-230.html